# How to set the property of an object from an onmove event inside said object?

Tags: javascript, events

I am creating an object that itself creates an object with some events associated.
When the event is fired I'd like to change an attribute of the top object.

Here is a MWE of the problem I'm dealing with `interact.js`:

```js
function MyObject() {
  this.attribute = 0

  function onMove(event) {
    this.attribute = 1;
  }

  const draggable = interact('#draggable')
  draggable.draggable({
    onmove: onMove
  })
}

let testObject = new MyObject()

document.querySelector('#draggable').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = testObject.attribute;
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  draggable
</div>

Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

The result is always be 0, and no amount of dragging will change it to 1.

I know the problem comes from here:

```
function onStart(event) {
    this.attribute = 1;
  }
```

The `this` is I believe not correct, but I don't know how to refer to the attribute of `MyObject`.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I would change the click listener to an `onmouseup` handler so that it updates when you finish dragging

Comment: @JoshLind thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind `this` like this:

```js
  draggable.draggable({
    onmove: onMove.bind(this)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! For a reason I didn't think of using `bind()` in there. That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

That is one way to do it:

```
function createObject () { // Use a regular function
  var attribute = 0 // Create a "private variable"

  function onMove(event) {
    attribute = 1;
  }

  const draggable = interact('#draggable')
  draggable.draggable({
    onmove: onMove
  })

  return {  // Return an object...
    get attribute () { // ...with an "attribute" property with only a getter...
      return attribute // ...that returns the attribute
    }
  }
}

let testObject = createObject()

document.querySelector('#draggable').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Acess testObject.attribute like you would a normal property
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = testObject.attribute;
  // testObject.attribute cannot be changed from outside
});
```